# Installing ReportLab onto Windows 64-bit server

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab

I would like to install ReportLab onto a Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit server from there is no internet access. I using Python 2.79 64-bit.

I went to this [page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab/) using my workstation (not the server). Clicked on the link for reportlab-3.2.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl and thought I would get the .whl file. Instead, I was able to download the reportlab-3.2.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.zip file which contained two folders.

I then copied the zip file over to the server into the D:\Python27\Scripts folder.

What should I do to install ReportLab? I tried "pip install reportlab-3.2.0-cp27-none-win_amd64", but it tried to go out to the internet (which the server doesn't have access to).

Can somebody assist me with some instructions?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a zip then probably need to unbundle it and run the setup.py script inside.

Comment: Thanks but there's no setup.py file. However, the odd thing is when downloading the same link at home, it downloads and saves as a .whl file. At work, it saved as a .zip file.

Comment: If I rename the .zip file to .whl, what is the proper pip install syntax to designate using the local .whl file and not having it go to the internet to download any files?

Comment: pip install reportlab-3.2.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl where reportlab-3.2.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is in the current working directory